# Unable to import Pandas because of Numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, installation, environment-variables

I keep receiving the below error when trying to import Pandas. From reading other posts online, I think this has something to do with my setup and/or environment variables, but I have tried everything and am still having issues.

I've attached a screenshot of the error I am receiving.

Any insight / help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Bryan

Import Pandas Error:

[image]

Comment: try uninstalling numpy and pandas and again install them

Comment: I've tried reinstalling both numpy and pandas and haven't had any luck. I suspect it has something to do with my paths/environment variables, but am new to comp sci and do not fully understand the issue

Comment: Try installing blas and lapack again.

Comment: @Nachiket this isn't working either unfortunately. See attached screenshot.